# Can I add more steps to a Gibbs sampler without hurting the ergodicity of the chain?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs, ergodic

I have a Gibbs sampler that updates a system of $n$ variables $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ by each of the full conditional distributions. Let's say that I add a $n+1^{th}$ step: I also update $v^T(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, with $v\in R^n$. Since I update following the full conditional of $v^T(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, either by direct sampling or using a Metropolis step, no doubt that the stationary distribution will be preserved. However, does this risk to mess with the irreductibility (or any other property I have forgotten) of the chain and make my Gibbs sampler invalid ?

Comment: Adding steps cannot hurt with the irreducibility. Apart from adding time to the run, it cannot do much harm.

Comment: I was waiting for you Xi'an. Thank you !